# Joined inheritance strategy - good alternative to Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm currently working on a project where we have a "joined inheritance" database table setup. The setup is essentially similar to the following:

[image]

Where the records in each sub-table have a one-to-one relationship with the parent table. Right now, there are only a few sub-tables, but it's possible in the future that we could have many more.

I know that this can be done fairly easily with JPA/Hibernate, but my team is not keen on using it.

Here is the solution I'm leaning on without using Hibernate:

```
public interface PersonDao<T> {

  T create(T t);

  // other methods omitted for brevity
}

public class EmployeeDao implements PersonDao<Employee> {

  private static final String CREATE_SQL = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE...";

  @Override
  public Employee create(Employee employee) {
    // create Employee
  }
}

public class OwnerDao implements PersonDao<Owner> {
  /* same pattern as EmployeeDao */
}

public class PersonDaoFactory {

  public PersonDao dao(String type) {
    if (type.equals("OWNER")) {
      return new OwnerDao();
    } else if (type.equals("EMPLOYEE")) {
      return new EmployeeDao();
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("Could not find DAO for type '" + type + "'");
  }
}
```

My question is, is there a better solution for this scenario in regards to maintainability and good design, without using an ORM like Hibernate? It seems like this will make adding new types a considerable amount of work in comparison to when using Hibernate.

Comment: _Why_ does the team not want to use Hibernate? If the database schema only has a few tables then hand-writing the queries is reasonable, but if there are many tables, you'll most likely end up writing your own ORM, which is not a great idea. [ORM hate](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/OrmHate.html) by Martin Fowler is a good read on the subject.

Comment: @MickMnemonic - No one on the team (other than myself) has experience using it, and none of our many applications use any sort of ORM, so others are very reluctant to adopt it. Some also think it is overkill. I've relieved most of their qualms regarding it, but I'd like to investigate the best-case alternative as well, which I couldn't seem to find much info on for this particular case. Thanks for the article also, I'll take a look at it!